# Membership.GetUser() & MARS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, sql-server-mars

I'm using asp.net membership, and need to make a call to Membership.GetUser() while I have another open SQL connection, but my code dies at that call.  I have MultipleActiveResultSets=True in the connection string that is used by both my code and the Membership provider.  It appears that the Membership class is ignoring the MARS part of the connect string.

Any suggestions as to how I can get MARS to work with the Membership class so I can solve this problem?

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: "my code dies at that call" is not clear enough.  If an exception is thrown, please get the type, message, and call stack and add them to your question.  If it "dies" some other way, please be specific as to how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use separate connection string (one for data one for Membership provider) without option ‘MultipleActiveResultSets=True’ ?

Does it work then ? If it works you can use *SqlConnectionStringBuilder* to create new connection string (from the original) without MARS option.